# Remote autocomplete query

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm new in Angular and try to make a autocomplete form with content filtered in back-end. I have class and Interface for Terminal:

```
export class Terminal {
  constructor(
      public id: number,
      public name: string,
      public city: string,
      public country: string) {}
}


export interface ITermianlResponse {
  results: Terminal[];
```

Then I have a Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  search(value): Observable<ITermianlResponse> {
    return this.http.get<ITermianlResponse>('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/public/terminal_ac/?q=' + value)
    .pipe(
      tap((response: ITermianlResponse) => {
        response.results = response.results
          .map(terminal => new Terminal(terminal.id, terminal.name, terminal.city, terminal.country))
        return response;
      })
  );

  }
}
```

Back-end side receive my request and give an answer, as for Shan:

```
{"results": [{"id": "1", "name": "Shanghai Terminal", "city": "Shanghai", "country": "China"}], "pagination": {"more": false}}
```

My component is below:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  filteredTerminals: ITermianlResponse;
  terminalsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private Service: Service) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.terminalsForm = this.fb.group({
      terminalInput: null
    })

    this.terminalsForm.get('terminalInput').valueChanges
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        switchMap(value => this.Service.search(value)),
    ).subscribe(result => this.filteredTerminals = result);
  }


  displayFn(terminal: Terminal) {
    if (terminal) { return terminal.name; }
  }

}
```

And finally my html:

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]='terminalsForm'>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Choose a terminal" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName='terminalInput'>
  </mat-form-field>
  <span>Your choice is: {{terminalsForm.get('terminalInput').value | json}}</span>

  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let terminal of (filteredTerminals | async)?.results" [value]="terminal">
        <span>{{ terminal.name }}</span>
        <small> | ID: {{terminal.id}}</small>
      </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

As I said back-end receives my request, but browser console raise and error `SearchComponent.html:9 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument:`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: well, it most likely conntected to the async pipe. 
remove it.

Comment: @Talg123 that was simple, thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: if it's solved. you shouldn't tag the title as [solved]. might as well post an answer. what does solve your problem.

Comment: @Mukyuu ok, will do now. In process. Can you please also say why don't I get name, only Id of terminal?

Comment: do you mean from the "results" you're unable to show `{{ terminal.name }}` inside the `<span>` tag?

Comment: @Mukyuu yes, I get only 'Your choice is: { "id": "3" }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I wrote down,
your problem was in the async pipe you used  in

```
let terminal of (filteredTerminals | async)?.results
```

and of-course its because the filteredTerminals
are not observable or promise.